# IFS separate a string like "Hello","World","this","is, a boring", "line"

Tags: bash, ifs

I'm trying to parse a .csv file and I have some problems with IFS. 
The file contains lines like this:

```
"Hello","World","this","is, a boring","line"
```

The columns are separated with a comma, so I tried to explode the line with this code:

```
IFS=, read -r -a tempArr <<< "$line"
```

But I get this output:

```
"Hello"
"World"
"this"
"is
a boring"
"line"
```

I understand why, so I tried some other commands but I don't get my expected output.

```
IFS=\",\"
IFS=\",
IFS=',\"'
IFS=,\"
```

Every time the third element is seperated in 2 parts.
How can I use IFS to seperate the string to 5 parts like this?

```
"Hello"
"World" 
"this" 
"is, a boring" 
"line"
```

Comment: `IFS` isn't meant for parsing CSV files; it can only handle simple splitting that doesn't depend on whether the delimiter is quoted or not. Use a language that *does* have a CSV parser available.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this could *theoretically* be done in bash. And it shouldn't be that hard.

Comment: Not in pure BASH but probably gnu awk

Comment: CSV parsing is tricky, especially when it comes to fields with embedded commas. Take @chepner's advice and use other languages such as Python, Java, ... to correctly parse it.

Comment: `line='"Hello","World","this","is, a boring","line"'; IFS=\" read -r -a tempArr <<< "$line"; for i in 1 3 5 7 9; do echo "\"${tempArr[$i]}\""; done`

Comment: @Cyrus That assumes every field is quoted, which is not necessary in a CSV file. `hello,world,this,"is, a boring",line` is valid.

Comment: @impinball, yes, it definitely can be done in bash -- there's a library for it. But if you read what's actually in that library, it is in fact pretty hard.

Comment: see https://github.com/lhunath/scripts/blob/8ffc68fa4a7d745f0cf815c442605f59335aa5fe/bashlib/bashlib#L560 for the bashlib implementation of CSV parsing

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Parsing is hard, period. Bash, a substitution-based, stream-heavy shell language with poor low-level text manipulation support makes things even harder. And yes, I've written a few parsers, even for more complicated problems than this. I usually use JS, though.

Answer (score 0):

give this a try:

```
sed 's/","/"\n"/g' <<<"${line}"
```

`sed` has a search and replace command `s` which is using regex to search pattern.

The regex replaces `,` in `","` with new line char.

As a consequence each element is on a separate line.

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to use the gawk with `FPAT` to define what makes a valid string -

**Input** :

> "hello","world","this,is"

**Script** :

```
gawk -n 'BEGIN{FS=",";OFS="\n";FPAT="([^,]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")"}{$1=$1;print $0}' somefile.csv
```

**Output** :

> "hello"
>   "world"
>   "this,is"

Answer (score 0):

[bashlib](https://github.com/lhunath/scripts/blob/master/bashlib/bashlib) provides a `csvline` function. Assuming you've installed it somewhere in your PATH:

```
line='"Hello","World","this","is, a boring","line"'

source bashlib
csvline <<<"$line"
printf '%s\n' "${CSVLINE[@]}"
```

...output from the above being:

```
Hello
World
this
is, a boring
line
```

---

To quote the implementation (which is copyright [lhunath](http://stackoverflow.com/users/58803/lhunath), the below text being taken from [this specific revision of the relevant git repo](https://github.com/lhunath/scripts/blob/8ffc68fa4a7d745f0cf815c442605f59335aa5fe/bashlib/bashlib#L560)):

```
#  _______________________________________________________________________
# |__ csvline ____________________________________________________________|
#
#       csvline [-d delimiter] [-D line-delimiter]
#
# Parse a CSV record from standard input, storing the fields in the CSVLINE array.
#
# By default, a single line of input is read and parsed into comma-delimited fields.
# Fields can optionally contain double-quoted data, including field delimiters.
#
# A different field delimiter can be specified using -d.  You can use -D
# to change the definition of a "record" (eg. to support NULL-delimited records).
#
csvline() {
    CSVLINE=()
    local line field quoted=0 delimiter=, lineDelimiter=$'\n' c
    local OPTIND=1 arg
    while getopts :d: arg; do
        case $arg in
            d) delimiter=$OPTARG ;;
        esac
    done

    IFS= read -d "$lineDelimiter" -r line || return
    while IFS= read -rn1 c; do
        case $c in
            \")
                (( quoted = !quoted ))
                continue ;;
            $delimiter)
                if (( ! quoted )); then
                    CSVLINE+=( "$field" ) field=
                    continue
                fi ;;
        esac
        field+=$c
    done <<< "$line"
    [[ $field ]] && CSVLINE+=( "$field" ) ||:
} # _____________________________________________________________________
```